# Registration Page Error - 404 joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, http-status-code-404

here's the interesting thing - I've used this function before but for someone odd reason its stopped working and its sending me to a page that doesn't exist within my website or folder for that instance .... Example:

www(website).com/index.php/component/comprofiler/?task=registers

I use Joomla 2.5 - so what I did being that I thought maybe this folder /comprofiler/ is simply missing - I download Joomla 2.5 again and went into the components folder and there is no such folder there named /com_profiler/ .... so this folder doesn't exist in the joomla 2.5 package either ...

How do I fix this issue - and where exactly is the actually link supposed to go upon clicking 'create new account'? What PHP file do I edit with the new codes if there are new codes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder **com_profiler** comes from the extension [Community Builder](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210). It's not a default Joomla folder.

You simply need to download and install this extension (which is free), then the registration page should work.

Comment: thnx, i enabled the plugin and disable the System - CB Core Redirect plugin, now it work :)